# Django Model/Database Design

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-models

I have a question about how to design a django model.  Here is the problem.  I have one model, which is a table of URLs that can be submitted to my app.  I also, through a many to many relationship, have made the ability to combine the URLs into 'collections'.  This works just fine however, I would like to add the ability to order and reorder the links in a collection.  So for example, the list of links id [a,b,c,d].  User1 creates a collection of [d,a,c], while User2 creates a collection of [a,c,d], and User3 creates a collection of [c,d,b].  Is there a simple way to add this functionality with my current design?

I am using python3, django1.8 and postgres, if that matters at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a ManyToManyField connect via an intermediary model. This model can control the sorting of the entries. Take a look at for example this question and answer: [Django ManyToManyField ordering using through?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893955/django-manytomanyfield-ordering-using-through).