# Order a ManyToMany relationship, Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.8

With these models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    order_index = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order_index']
```

I've been trying to get the following code to work:

```
group = Group.objects.get(id=1)
group.members.all() # I want the resulting membership objects to ordered by order_index as default.
```

Is this possible? The answers to similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893955/django-manytomanyfield-ordering-using-through) require you to write `group.members.all().order_by(...)`. I am trying to have it so the results are ordered by `order_index` by default.

Comment: You need to give the Person the date_joined attribute and set a value either in a form, or use this parameter in your model for the date_joined attribute, auto_add_now=True. Then refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the user, and then the members associated with that user ordering them by date_joined. Not sure how you would do it automatically because the ordering is usually by the pk value which I'm assuming would correspond with the date joined because the higher the pk the later joined.

```
user = Person.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
get_members =  user.group.members.all().order_by('date_joined')
```

Comment: Ugh. My fault for copy/pasting code. If I was actually using date_joined this would work. Unfortunately, I'm actually using a user set value. I've updated the original post to reflect that.